# Will other users will be able to see count of upvotes & downvotes casted by me on Stack Overflow new profile pages?

Tags: discussion, support, voting, upvotes

The question is straight forward as in title.

In Old Stack Overflow profiles; users were able to see count of upvotes and downvotes casted by other users.

The new profile shows only total (upvotes + downvotes) votes casted by user.

For Ex: You visit a certain profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/user_no/user_display_name?tab=questions

In IMPACT section; It will show you total (upvotes + downvotes) votes casted by that user.

Will other users will be able to see count of upvotes & downvotes (separately) casted by me on Stack Overflow new profile pages too? and If yes.. How..?

**Part2:**

If they are able to see my upvote_count and downvote_count; I want to hide it from my profile for them(But not the count of total votes casted by me). Is it possible?

Comment: My mistake. I didn't notice activity tab. Went through the link I posted in post :) And it wasn't showing me my own count of upvotes and downvotes as I already said in comment below the accepted answer. :) Then I had look on 6 profiles. Then thought of posting question over here. By the way -`Part 2` was reasonable. Whether we can hide it from other users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will other users will be able to see count of upvotes & downvotes (separately) casted by me on Stack Overflow new profile pages too? and If yes.. How..?

Yes, go to the Activity tab and scroll down, there you'll see a table with the upvote/downvote count.

> If they are able to see my upvote_count and downvote_count; I want to hide it from my profile for them(But not the count of total votes casted by me). Is it possible?

No, you cannot choose to hide this info from your profile.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't check with activity tab.. :p went throgh the link I posted in post :)
And it wasn't showing me my own count of upvotes and downvotes :)
I can accept it as answer after 3 minutes :)